# SQL Server error when updating/creating records in database from PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Here is the function I use to send queries to SQL

```
function Invoke-SQL
{
param (
    [string]$server,
    [string]$database,
    [string]$Query
)

$connectionString = "Data Source=$server; " +
"Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
"Initial Catalog=$database"

$connection = new-object 
system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($Query, $connection)
$connection.Open()

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command

$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

$connection.Close()

$dataSet.Tables
}
```

When I run a query like this:

```
Invoke-SQL -server 'ServerName' -database 'DBname' -Query "SELECT * FROM [DBname].[dbo].[TableName] WHERE UserID = '$userid' AND ComputerName = '$computername'"
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."
PSDesk_Client.ps1 (358, 2): ERROR: At Line: 358 char: 2
ERROR: +     $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
ERROR: +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], 
MethodInvocationException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
ERROR:
ERROR: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."
PSDesk_Client.ps1 (358, 2): ERROR: At Line: 358 char: 2
ERROR: +     $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
ERROR: +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], 
MethodInvocationException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
ERROR:
```

It seems it is having this error twice because:

- First, it runs a query to get information from the database
- Second, it runs a query to create/update information as needed on the database

Whether I have it return the data or just send a command it is unhappy with `$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null`. Why are my two uniqueidentifiers causing this error and what can I do to fix this?

Upon trying to enter in a record manually, it throws an error:

> Error Message: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes.

Is `uniqueidentifier` the wrong data type then? It needs to be a string but certainy shouldn't be required to be in that format or any format

Comment: I believe it's treating `'$userid'` as a string and not as what you want. Same for `$computername`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i'll do some troubleshooting with that, thanks for the suggestion. I'll reply with what I find out.

Comment: Upon trying to enter in a record manually, it throws an error: `Error Message: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes`. Is 'uniqueidentifier' the wrong data type then? It needs to be a string but certainy shouldn't be required to be in that format or any format

Comment: This is a SQL Server error, not PowerShell. I tagged appropriately to bring those experts here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922651/bug-error-message-when-you-try-to-save-a-maintenance-plan-in-sql-serve

Comment: What datatype is `UserID` and `ComputerName`? SQL will try and do implicit data conversion.

Comment: I changed `UserID` and `ComputerName` to varchar (maybe not the right choice but it works), and made them composite primary keys. Previously they were set as uniqueidentifiers(didn't know what this was when I originally tried it). It's now giving me the functionality that I was looking for